# Why can I not create a element of canvas with createElement?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to create the canvas internally and then just use it normally in my javascript.  The following code creates the canvas.

**Question: I should be able to create a canvas with the document.createElement("sketchpad")?**

```
 var canvas = document.createElement("sketchpad");
```

Code:

```
function init() 
{
    //canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

    var canvas = document.createElement("sketchpad");
    //var ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width  = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    if (canvas.getContext)
    {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    if (ctx) 
    {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup',   sketchpad_mouseUp,   false);
    }
}
```

All the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sketchpad</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var mouseDown = 0;

    function drawDot(ctx,x,y,size) 
    {
        r=0; 
        g=0; 
        b=0; 
        a=256;

        ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";
        ctx.fill();
    } 

    function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) 
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function sketchpad_mouseDown() 
    {
        mouseDown=1;
        drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,4);
    }

    function sketchpad_mouseUp() 
    {
        mouseDown=0;
    }

    function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) 
    { 
        getMousePos(e);

        if (mouseDown==1) 
        {
            drawDot(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,4);
        }
    }

    function getMousePos(e) 
    {
        if (!e)
        {
            var e = event;
        }

        if (e.offsetX) 
        {
            mouseX = e.offsetX;
            mouseY = e.offsetY;
        }
        else if (e.layerX) 
        {
            mouseX = e.layerX;
            mouseY = e.layerY;
        }
     }

    function init() 
    {
        //canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

        var canvas = document.createElement("sketchpad");
        //var ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width  = 500;
        canvas.height = 500;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        if (canvas.getContext)
        {
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        }

        if (ctx) 
        {
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup',   sketchpad_mouseUp,   false);
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
.leftside 
{
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#def;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.rightside 
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}

#sketchpad 
{
    float:left;
    border:4px solid #888;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
        <div class="leftside">
           <input type="submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
        </div>

        <div class="rightside">
         <!--  <canvas id="sketchpad" height="500" width="500">-->
        </canvas>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**This new code did not work:**

This new code does not work, this is how a person has to create the canvas correct.

```
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //or what ever name that I want
 canvas.id  = "sketchpad";
```

The if statement is not necessary, is it?

```
function init() 
{
    //canvas   = document.getElementById('sketchpad');
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id  = "sketchpad";

    if (canvas.getContext)
    {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    if (ctx) 
    {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup',   sketchpad_mouseUp,   false);
    }
}
```

Code here: This code does not seem to work either. I appended the sketchpad to the canvas but it still is not adding it to the document.

```
function init() 
{
    //canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = "sketchpad";
    document.getElementById('sketchpad').appendChild(canvas);

    if (canvas.getContext)
    {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    if (ctx) 
    {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup',   sketchpad_mouseUp,   false);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sketchpad is not a valid DOM element so it will create a [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement). This is not what you are looking for.

You want to create a canvas, so lets just create a canvas:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

And give it the ID "sketchpad" if you want:

```
canvas.id = "sketchpad";
```

Once you canvas is created, you will need to append it to an existing element of your HTML if you want it to be shown. Ex. if you want your canvas to appear in a div that looks like this:

```
<div id="rightside" class="rightside">
```

You would append your canvas like this:

```
document.getElementById('rightside').appendChild(canvas);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WCX7Q/1/) is a jsFiddle using your code!

Thats it!

--

Additional source for [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

Comment: This is not working completely. Is there any way that you can paste up a completely working HTML.

Comment: Still does not seem to be working? What am I missing?

Comment: @DougHauf The canvas that you created is the sketchpad. by doing `document.getElementById('sketchpad').appendChild(canvas);`, you try to append your canvas to your canvas... Where in your page do you want to see your canvas(sketchpad)?

Comment: If you want your sketchpad it at the right of your button having value "clear Sketchpad", you need to append your canvas in the div having class "rightside". Change `<div class="rightside">` to `<div id="rightside" class="rightside">` and do this `document.getElementById('rightside').appendChild(canvas);`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. In your opinion which is the best way of doing it. Putting it in the HTML code or creating it with javascript?